Google reCAPTCHA V3 "Browser Error" Not All the Time In different browsers and devices
We have a WooCommerce site using Contact Form 7 with Google reCAPTCHA v3.
It works.
The site uses the same reCAPTCHA and the login page works.
The site was migrated to a subdomain.
On the new site, no reCAPTCHA icon shows up.
The form doesn't submit.
Both sites are identical. Thus, no plugins interfere. It's not the browser.
No debug.log is written.
No error_log is written.
PHP email works on the server as tested with an independent code.
We tried the plugin that allows Contact Form 7 to use v2 but there is no place to enter the code/key for that.
I work remotely with another person who is experiencing the same, thus I don't believe it's a bad internet connection. I have fiber optic > 70 Mbps.
Any unique/uncommon ideas is appreciated because we did a thorough test. It works on one site but not the other with identical information, data, templates, plugins, configurations (except the domain, of course).
